# Prove by induction that $ 2^{n+2}|(2n+3)! $ is true for all positive integers n

Tags: proof-writing, induction, factorial

I am trying to prove that

$$ 2^{n+2}|(2n+3)! $$

Is true for all all positive integers $ n $.

I started proving it by induction and shown that the base case $ n = 1$ is true. Then I proceeded to $k$:
$$ 2^{k+2}|(2k+3)! \implies (2k+3)! = m2^{k+2} \implies 2^{k+2} =  \frac{(2k+3)!}m$$, for some integer $m$.

Now the inductive step:
$2^{k+1+2} = 2^{k+2}2 = \frac{(2k+5)!}m$ for some integer $m$.

I got stuck on this step. How would I continue to solve this?

Comment: You did not specify what statemenet you want to prove.

Comment: What do you mean "true"? Do you mean an integer?

Comment: $(2k+3)! = m2^{k+2}\iff 2^{k+2}\mid(2k+3)!$

Comment: The usual notation for "$a$ divides $b$ evenly (without remainder)" is $a|b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the division operation $\div$ with the divisibility relation $|$.

> $$ 2^{k+2}|(2k+3)! \implies (2k+3)! = m2^{k+2} $$

This is true, except you forgot to quantify $m$.  It's better to say that $2^{k+1} \mathrel| (2k+3)!$ implies *there exists* $m$ such that $(2k+3)! = m2^{k+2}

> $$ (2k+3)! = m2^{k+2} \implies 2^{k+2} =  (2k+3)!|m$$

No.  I think you mean $\frac{(2k+3)!}{m}$ on the right-hand side of the second equation above.  But I'm not sure that helps anyway.

You want to show that $(2(k+1)+3)! = (2k+5)!$ is a multiple of $2^{(k+1)+2} = 2^{k+3}$.  That is, you want to show that $(2k+5)! = n2^{k+3}$ for some integer $n$.

Observe that
$$
    (2k+5)! = (2k+5)(2k+4)(2k+3)! = (2k+5)(2k+4)2^{k+2}m
$$
and you want to show the right-hand side is a multiple of $2^{k+3}$.  Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Given $2^{k+2}|(2k+3)!$ you have $2^{k+1+2}=2\cdot 2^{k+2}$ divides $(2(k+1)+3)!=(2k+3)!(2k+4)(2k+5)$ because $2k+4$ is even and contributes at least one more factor $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Without induction, the $\,n+1\,$ numbers $\,2, 4, 6, \ldots, 2n+2\,$ are all even, and are all factors of $\,(2n+3)!\,$, so $\,2^{n+1} \mid (2n+3)!\,$. Also $\,2n+3 \ge 5\,$ so $\,4\,$ is always among the factors of the factorial, which gives an additional factor of $\,2\,$, so in the end $\,2 \cdot 2^{n+1} = 2^{n+2} \mid (2n+3)!\,$.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption for $k$ is:
$$2^{k+2}|(2k+3)!\text.$$
The inductive step is to prove, from that assumption, that:
$$2^{k+3}|(2k+5)!\\
\iff (2k+5)!=2^{k+3}m\\
\iff (2k+5)(2k+4)(2k+3)!=2\times2^{k+2}m$$
for some integer $m$.

Let $(2k+3)!=m_12^{k+2}$. From the assumption, $m_1$ is an integer. So, the inductive step becomes
$$(2k+5)(2k+4)m_1=2m\\
\iff\frac{(2k+5)(2k+4)m_1}2=m\\
\iff(2k+5)(k+2)m_1=m\text.$$
Consider that the left-hand side is an integer. Q.E.D.